# Why do default Storyboard apps have a second interface declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard

Sorry if this is stupid... but it confuses me?...

I'm trying a new storyboard app with Xcode and just asked myself why there is a second declaration of the @interface in my implementation file?

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

 }

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

....

@end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html

It's a class extension, subtly different from a category, since it has no name inside the parentheses. You use it for declaring properties and methods that are intended to be kept private (out of the header), and redeclaring publicly read-only properties and methods as privately read-write. This allows for cleaner encapsulation.

By request, a friendly example:

JYDuckPondManager.h

```
@interface JYDuckPondManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSUInteger duckCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) CGFloat    waterLevel;

- (JYDuckReaction *)feedDucks:(JYDuckFood *)food;
- (JYDuckReaction *)harassDucks:(JYDuckTaunt *)taunt;

@end
```

JYDuckPondManager.m (extension, imaginary implementation omitted)

```
@interface JYDuckPondManager ()

//// Redefined for internal modification
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) NSUInteger duckCount;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat    waterLevel;

//// Internally exclusive properties
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet  *duckPersonalitySet;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat flockAnxietyLevel;

//// Private messages
- (void)recalculatePondState;

@end
```

Other objects should be able to interact with the pond, but they're not supposed to know certain things going on in the pond or redefine the pond's statistics. Keeping nuts-and-bolts stuff in the .m extension ensures that the .h is concise and appropriately limited.

Comment: what's a typical use-case for the need of this functionality?

Answer (score 4):

The second @interface block in the .m file is an extension. You could add declarations for methods and instance variables you want to use internally within your class.

Answer (score 3):

The second interface `@interface ViewController ()` is a class extension which is like an anonymous category. A class extension is declared like a category only without a name. Declarations found in these extensions directly extend the declarations found in the class’s primary `@interface` and can sometimes *(in some situations)* override declarations found in the primary interface.